# error for NMinimize with Parameters in the form f[a_]:=NMinimize

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation

I'm trying to write a function of a variable as the argument of a minimization where that variable comes to play.

Here is the code :

```
f[x_, a_, b_] = x*Log[x] + (1 - x)*Log[1 - x ] - a*x^2 + b*x^4;
mu[x_, a_, b_] = D[f[x, a, b], x];
h[x_, a_, b_] = D[f[x, a, b], x, x];
solh[a_, b_] := {Min[x /. NSolve[{h[x, a, b] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x]], 
   Max[x /. NSolve[{h[x, a, b] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x]]};

p[x_, a_, b_] = f[x, a, b] - x*mu[x, a, b];

fm[a_, b_] := 
  NMinimize[{(mu[x0, a, b] - mu[x1, a, b])^2 + (p[x0, a, b] - 
        p[x1, a, b])^2, 
    0.0001 < x0 < solh[a, b][[1]] && 
     solh[a, b][[2]] < x1 < 0.9999}, {x0, x1}];

amin = 2;
amax = 82;
da = 5;
bmin = 10;
bmax = 100;
db = 20;

X = Table[Table[fm[a, b], {a, amin, amax, da}], {b, bmin, bmax, db}];
A = Table[a, {a, amin, amax, da}];
X0 = Transpose[{A, x0 /. X[[All, 2]]}];
X1 = Transpose[{A, x1 /. X[[All, 2]]}];
ListPlot[{X0, X1}]
```

But I'm then getting the error :

> NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid
>    $\{0.0001<x0,x<x1,x0<x,x1<0.9999\}. $
>   Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications 
>   involving the variables.

So I was wondering how to proceed !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some values of `a` and `b` there is no solutions in the range `0<x<1`, so `solh[a_, b_]` shows `{x, x}`, hence further errors. You can change this to:

```
solh[a_, b_] := 
  With[{sol = NSolve[{h[x, a, b] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x][[;; , 1, 2]]}, 
   If[sol != {}, MinMax[sol], {0.00011, 0.99989}]];
```

Now in case of no solutions due to restrictions on `x` the output will be `{0.00011, 0.99989}`, you can tune these values. Then we can simplify your `Table`s:

```
points = Flatten[
  Table[{a, x0, x1} /. fm[a, b][[2]], {b, bmin, bmax, db}, {a, amin, 
    amax, da}], 1];
```

and show `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[{points[[;; , {1, 2}]], points[[;; , {1, 3}]]}, PlotLegends -> {x0, x1}]
```

[image]